# rails: how to include additional fields in json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join, activerecord

I am using acts_as_follower in my rails application so that a user can follow a book. My controller is given below. I also have a current_user method.

I want to add an additional field "isFolowing" to the pages response ,This is to check if the current user is following that particular page or not. acts_as_follower gem provides a method user.following?(book) to check if a user is following a particular book.

Please help me to add this additional field "isFollowing" to the response

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @books=Book.all
       render json: @books
   end
end
```

Comment: if you want to have  isFollowing in response, render json: {isFollowing: current_user.isFollowing?(book)}.

Comment: Saravanan, I want to see isFollowing for each of the books in the index action response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you need to have a method in Book class,

```
def attributes_with_following_flag(user)
     as_json.merge({is_following: user.is_following(this)})
end

And in controller,

 render json: @books.collect{|b| b.attributes_with_following_flag(current_user)}
```

Comment: In the controller method, it should be `current_user` instead of `user`

Comment: thanks a lot for reply @Saravanan .but the user.following?(book) method provided by the gem acts_as_follower is only working if you call from controller and not inside the model. is there anyway we can do this using the "joins" and "includes"

Comment: act_as_follower also provides, book.followed_by? method.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion @Saravanan your code is right. i wasnt getting current user in my controller. fixed it. :)